# How to restart all subscriptions done by Redis after Redis is restarted?

Tags: redis

Once the Redis server is restarted, how to start all the processes which were run by Redis instance?

Here in my application, I can see that Redis instance is created, but all the subscriptions which the Redis instance was doing, is not restarted. Hence application is not able to receive new messages from the event bus/ Redis bus.

Answer (score 2):

You application needs to capture the disconnect event and, once the database is back online, reconnect to it and resubscribe to the relevant channels.